# Preventing Certain Users from Deleting Records in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, filter, rails-admin

I have Rails Admin installed which is working great. However I have a problem. Only admins can sign into Rails Admin and there are two types of admins. The first type of admin can have access to everything, delete anything they want, etc. The second type should only have access to certain tables.

I don't see any configuration with Rails Admin to get what I want so I was thinking of using a callback in my models. But then I would have to somehow pass through the user's credentials to verify what type of admin they are, and even then there would have to be a lot of hacking. My question is, can this be done, and if so, whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used CanCan in the past to accomplish exactly what you're looking for. It worked well with Rails Admin.

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCan

As an aside: I would recommend using a single role per user as that seems to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks. You're right in that I should refactor my code to have multiple models for different users. It was a rush job and looking back I see the issues.

Comment: Jason, just to clarify, I didn't mean a different model for different users. CanCan allows you to assign multiple roles to each user to account for different permission levels. I found it simpler to use a single role per user and give descriptive names to the roles that make clear what the permissions are.